# Split Строка в Java Android

Tags: java, android, строки

По запросу на сервер приходит строка, которую я делю и вывожу на экран:

```
public void onSuccess(Context c, String result){
    String d = "<pub>"; 
    String[] public = result.split("<pub>");
    for(String pub: public){
        LinearLayout p = getPage(pub);
        main.addView(p);
    }
}
```

проблема в том, что если сервер возвращает строку без символов переменной d, он по понятным причинам выкидывает из приложения. Не могу написать проверку, чтобы, если возвратилась непонятная строка, он выводил, например, метод `error()`.
Думаю понятно объяснил.

Comment: "Думаю понятно объяснил." - ошибаетесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классе `String` в `Java` есть замечательный метод  `contains(CharSequence s)` проверяющий наличие подстроки в строке и возвращающий `true` при её наличии и `false` при отсутствии подстроки в строке.

Далее.

Прервать работу можно выкинув исключение.

Для этого исключение нужно сначала создать.

```
public class SubstringNotFoundException extends Exception {
    //...
}
```

Далее нужно всех уведомить что Ваш метод может выбрасывать что-то нехорошее

```
public void onSuccess(Context c, String result) throws SubstringNotFoundException {
    //...
}
```

Итого получаем:

```
public void onSuccess(Context c, String result) throws SubstringNotFoundException {
    String d = "<pub>"; 
    if(!result.contains(d))
        throw new SubstringNotFoundException();
    String[] public = result.split(d);
    for(String pub: public){
        LinearLayout p = getPage(pub);
        main.addView(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я раньше не слышал о таком и вообще только начал изучать java так что много не ругайте за нубский вопрос)) А так большое спс

Comment: @user8978194, удачи в освоении! Задавайте вопросы ещё.)

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean checkStr(String s){
    return s.contains("<pub>");
}

public void onSuccess(Context c, String result){
    if (checkStr(result)){
        //Если в строке присутствует тег <pub> то
        String[] public = result.split("<pub>");
        for(String pub: public){
            LinearLayout p = getPage(pub);
            main.addView(p);
        }
    } else {
        // Иначе
    }
}
```